# JSON POST parsing issue in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to post data suing POST request, but whenever i am posting data I am getting Bad Request error.

Please check this code and if there any issue please let me know,

```
func callDataCall()
{
  let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "REQUEST_URL")!

    //convert MID dict to jsondata
    let NewJSONData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["Disease_request":["Mid":self.MedicationID]], options: [])

    //  Convert jsondata to string
    let NewJSONDataString = NSString(data:NewJSONData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String

    print("Created Dictionary is : \(NewJSONDataString)")

    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)

    // set up the session
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    urlRequest.httpBody = NewJSONDataString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest)
    {
        data, response, error in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        print("status code is :\(httpResponse)")

        if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 201)
        {
            do
            {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]

                if let content = json?["Disease"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                {
                    for i in 0..<content.count
                    {
                        self.medicationContent.append(content[i] as AnyObject)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.tableview_Medication.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

            self.stopIndicator()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Response is :

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000231e40> { URL: "REQUEST_URL" } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 46;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 30 Nov 2016 10:38:24 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    "X-Powered-By-Plesk" = PleskWin;
} }
```

I am using the same logic for Objective C, its working fine for me.

Comment: `let reqJSONString = "\("{\"Disease_request\":") \(JSONDataString) \("}")"` do you really need to embed JSONString into JSON? Also, you may need to set the length of it in the header.

Comment: actually post content should be like as: 

{"Disease_request": {
  "Mid" : "37"
} }

Comment: Please refactor your code to use Swift native types (`URL`, `URLRequest`, `String`, `[String:Any]`) and the standard JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` in Swift 3. And forget `PrettyPrinted`. The server doesn't care at all.

Comment: So for now i have convert the code as below,

 let MedicationIDDict:NSDictionary = ["Mid":self.MedicationID]
 let reqJSONString = ["Disease_request":(MedicationIDDict)]
        
        let NewJSONData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: reqJSONString, options: .prettyPrinted)
        
        //  Convert jsondata to string
        let NewJSONDataString = NSString(data:NewJSONData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String

But still getting 400 status code response

Comment: `let newJSONData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:["Disease_request":["Mid":self.MedicationID]], options:[])`?

Comment: I tried this also, still same issue i am getting.

Comment: I have just update code in Question

Comment: "I am using the same logic for Objective C, its working fine for me.": Could you show your Objective-C code then? To try to spot a difference?

Comment: NSDictionary *loginDataDict = @{@"Mid" : self.medicationID};
    
     NSError *error = nil;
      // Serialize the dictionary
     NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:loginDataDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
      NSString *JSONDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
     NSString  *reqJSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", @"{\"Disease_request\":", JSONDataString, @"}"];

  NSData *postData = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

Comment: NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

Comment: Almost all the `[request setValue:someValue forHTTPHeaderField:someHeaderKey];` are missing in your Swift version. Also, the post body encoding is different, any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution !!

The Swift code is fine, i need to add one more line after **httpMethod**

So now the code as like this

> urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
>
> urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")